# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property Tree of # which has only a getter

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm using Vue 3 with `<script setup>` and I'm getting an error when I'm trying to use a component.

In Vue 2, it worked like this:

```html
<template>
    <Tree />
</template>

<script>
    import { Tree, Fold, Draggable } from 'he-tree-vue'

    export default {
        components: {
            Tree: Tree.mixPlugins([ Fold, Draggable ])
        },
     }
</script>
```

I would like to do this using Vue 3 and `<script setup>` but I'm getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property Tree of # which has only a getter

```html
<template>
    <Tree />
</template>

<script setup>
    import { Tree, Fold, Draggable } from 'he-tree-vue'

    Tree = Tree.mixPlugins([ Fold, Draggable ]) // This is causing an error
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to occur with trying to re-assign an import. Instead of reassigning it, rename the `Tree` import, and export your own `Tree` constant:

```html
<template>
  <Tree :value="treeData">
    <template v-slot="{ node, path, tree }">
      <span>
        <b @click="tree.toggleFold(node, path)">
          {{node.$folded ? '+' : '-'}}
        </b>
        {{node.text}}
      </span>
    </template>
  </Tree>
</template>

<script setup>
import { Tree as HeTree, Fold, Draggable } from 'he-tree-vue'
const Tree = HeTree.mixPlugins([ Fold, Draggable ])

const treeData = [{text: 'node 1'}, {text: 'node 2', children: [{text: 'node 2-1'}]}]
</script>
```

[demo](https://github.com/tony19-sandbox/vue3-he-tree-in-script-setup-demo)